# How to get expiry date for cached item?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I store an object in MemoryCache:

```
void foo()
{
  ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
  SomeClass obj = cache["CACHE_KEY"] as SomeClass;
  if (null == obj )
  {
     obj = new SomeClass(); ....
     CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
     //update
     policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now+TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
     cache.Set("CACHE_KEY", obj, policy);
  }
  else
  {
     //get expiry date 
  }
  .....
}
```

Is it possible to get expiration date somehow if cache contains the object ?

Comment: Why not create a composite object that contains the object to cache and its expiry date?

Comment: @Jeremy McGee: It will work, but maybe there is another way to do so... I just want to make sure I don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are setting the sliding expiration, isn't it always 10 minutes from the time you accessed it? if the object is null, the cache entry has expired and if not, the expiration (in the code above) is always 10 minutes from the time you checked?

Or you could have a base object (that all your cacheable objects inherits from) with the expiry time as a property that is set at the time you add to cache. When you extract the object, you check for the property and you have the expiration time to calculate the difference. Just a thought.

Comment: Oops, my bad - it's supposed to be `AbsoluteExpiration`, I just pasted it from the wrong source , +1 for pointing it out.

Comment: added another option to my answer, not sure if that will work for you or not. I see someone added a comment to the same effect, but I was first ;)

Comment: (second option) -  it will work, but I believe it can be a better way to do so(I'm not sure though; maybe it is the only option).

Comment: why do you need the expiry time?

Comment: It's gonna be a part of the message sent back to client (the code is part of request handler).

Comment: I don't see any straightforward way of doing this. Is adding entry to an xml file an option if you don't want to modify entities. Not sure, its a hack anyway.

Comment: Thanks, adding an extra property seems to be the only way to keep it simple.

Comment: "Isn't it always 10 minutes from the time you accessed it" And that would be ... when? I presume the point of wanting to be able to do the test is that you don't know when someone last accessed it. And presumably you don't want your check of the expiration time to count as an access that resets a sliding expiration, as that would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

As said, save expiry value once saving the object to memory cache,

```
cache.Set(DataKey, DataToStore, policy);
cache.Set("MemCacheExpiry", DateAndTime.Now.AddHours(6), policy);
```

Then read expiry from expiry key:

```
public static DateTime CheckCachedExpiry()
{
    DateTime MemCacheExpiryDate = default(DateTime);
    MemCacheExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MemoryCache.Default.Get("MemCacheExpiry"));
    return MemCacheExpiryDate;
}
```

Comment: Well, I suppose. But presumably the Cache object knows when the expiration time is. One would think there would be a way to ask it without having to recalculate the time independently.