# How to check when an item in MemoryCache will expire?

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

Is it possible to read the expiration time of an item in MemoryCache?

I'm using the .NET `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` to store my configuration information for 30 min before I reload it from the database. As part of a status page I would like to show how old a specific cache item is or when it will expire.

```
object config = LoadSomeStuffFromDatabase();
CacheItemPolicy cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30) }; 
Cache.Add("MyConfigKey", config, cachePolicy);

// And now I want to do something like this :-)
DateTime dt = Cache.SomeMagicMethod("MyConfigKey");
```

Today I'm using a variable that is updated every time I reload the configuration. But it would be much nicer to read this information from the cache itself.

Comment: One alternative would be to cache your insertion date along with your object, that way, when you fetch it later, you will know *when* you did save it, and you can calculate how long it'll take to expire

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that this has already been answered:

[How to get expiry date for cached item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739130/how-to-get-expiry-date-for-cached-item)

If that isn't what you're looking for, consider the following:

The API doesn't support getting the policy back from the retrieval of the cached item.  Since you can cache any object, you could cache the policy in conjunction with the object and do some time based comparisons when you need to later access the object.

Comment: The linked answer relates to SlidingExpiration. But the design suggestion from both you and @Matias-Cicero is better than maintaining it separately.I already have base object so it matched my requirement pretty good.

Comment: this is a very poor API in my opinion. caching the policy as a first-class entry  rather than metadata against the cacheitem is very poor form.

Answer (score 0):

The cache provides the tools to do what you want. You just have to do the programmer work:

```
object config = LoadSomeStuffFromDatabase();

DateTime expirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
CacheItemPolicy cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = expirationDate }; 

Cache.Add("MyConfigKey", config, cachePolicy);
Cache.Add("MyConfigKey/ExpirationDate", expirationDate, cachePolicy);

// Now do something like this
DateTime dt = Cache.Get("MyConfigKey/ExpirationDate");
```